# Instantiating a Component in React

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I'm making a wizard form but I can't get the first component called tableResults to load. I have a state called step which changes depending on the component. Currently the initial state of the step is set to 1. How would I make tableResults show up when the state is 1?

Step1.js snippet

```
import tableResults from './tableResults';

class Step1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
     this.state = {
      step: 1
    }
  }


render() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    previousPage,
    step
  } = this.props;


    return (  
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <div className="step-container">

          {step === 1 && <tableResults/>}
          </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Table Snippet:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

class tableResults extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    }

  render() {

    return (  
      <div>
        This is the table
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the state from props, but instead you should get it from state as follows:

```js
import tableResults from './tableResults';

class Step1 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
     this.state = {
      step: 1
    }
  }


render() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    previousPage,
    step
  } = this.props;


    return (  
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <div className="step-container">

          {this.state.step === 1 && <tableResults/>}
          </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that did the trick, however, my tableresults component is not showing up. Is the code correct for this?

Comment: Name your components with first letter as uppercase. It should work then.